# Ember-cli Error while processing route: category.index

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

This is my first project with EmberJS and Ember-CLI.
I run the following commands:

```
ember new site  //version: 0.1.2
ember generate resource categories
```

I get the following answer and the tests:

```
  create app/models/category.js
  create app/routes/categories.js
  create app/templates/categories.hbs

ember generate resource category
```

I get the following answer and the tests:

```
  create app/routes/category.js
  create app/templates/category.hbs
  identical app/models/category.js
```

The router.js file has:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('categories', function() { });
  this.resource('category', { path: 'categories/:category_id' }, function() { });
});
```

When I visit `dev:4200/categories/1` I get the following error:

```
 GET http://dev:4200/categories/1 404 (Not Found)
 Error while processing route: category.index
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?
All the files are generated by ember-cli in their default state.

EDIT: I have a `models/category.js`

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr()
});
```

And in the `routes/category.js`

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    console.log({category_id: params.category_id});
//    return this.store.find('category', params.category_id);
  }
});
```

The route `dev:4200/categories/1` works and console.log shows the value `Object {category_id: "1"}` but with `return this.store` I get the error above.

Answer (score 3):

I solve it by creating a FixtureAdapter and adding some fixtures to the model.

`ember generate adapter application`

```
export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({    
});
```

`models/category.js`

```
var Category = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  img: DS.attr('string'),
  cnt: DS.attr('number')
});

Category.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Writing a blog in Ember",
            cnt: 8,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Writing a blog",
            cnt: 5
        }
    ]
});

export default Category;
```

The error was misleading. Now it works just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are expecting the behavior of  a `route` not a `resource`.

The following will generate two routes `category` and `category.index`.

```
this.resource('category', { path: '/categories/:category_id' }, function() { });
```

Navigating to `http://dev:4200/categories/1` is going to route you first through `CategoryRoute` then `CategoryIndexRoute`

Try this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('categories', function() { });
  this.route('category', { path: '/categories/:category_id' }, function() { });
});
```

Or more canonically this.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('categories', function() {
    this.route('show', {path: '/:category_id'});
  });
});
```